# Using ng-options in a JSON object

Tags: angularjs

I have JSON data like this

```
{
total_number: 10,
apples: "["2500","1200"]",
oranges: "["500","200"]",
veggies_name: "["Summer Veggies","Winter Veggies"]"
}
```

In veggies_name I have Summer Veggies and Winter Veggies. I want to display them in  select tags. The first option should display Summer Veggies and second option should display Winter Veggies and if there is a third one, It should display in a third option without quotes and square brackets.

How do I use ng-options for that.

EDIT: In my controller I did something like this

```
        $http({
        method:'POST',
        url: ''
    }).then(function(response2){

        var things = response2.data;

        $scope.veggies_name = things.veggies_name.split(",");
        console.info($scope.veggies_name);
```

And in my view

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item for item in veggies_name"></select>
```

Now its displaying two options like

`["Summer Veggies"
"Winter Veggies"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid,

change it as,

```
{
"total_number": 10,
"apples": [2500,1200],
"oranges": [2500,1200],
"veggies_name": ["Summer Veggies","Winter Veggies"]
}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/BozTOdQkBJnSdcZXpLy8?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you. I am calling it from an API so can't change it now

Comment: you can run a for loop and modify

Comment: In your Plunker, why does it have an extra empty value on top

Comment: i.e because we have not set the default element check the updated demo https://plnkr.co/edit/BozTOdQkBJnSdcZXpLy8?p=preview

Comment: Thanks I already figured that out. Also Can you please check the EDIT I made in the question

Comment: you are displaying the plain string